# Send post with jquery and load a specific selector

Tags: php, jquery, json, post

i want to Post a form value with Jquery $.POST() and load a specific selector 
i don't know how to do it may be with json or something like that

```
$.post('topic.php', {id: id}, function(data){
    $("#message").html(data);
    $("#message").hide();
    $("#message").slideDown(500); //Fade in the data given by the topic.php file
});
```

i just want to load the title and description not the whole page

i want to retrieve this title and description in a lightbox how can i do it?

Comment: Which elements on topic.php hold the title and description? Are those tags from the `<head>` of the page?

Comment: JSON sounds cool, it's gonna work ok. It's light via user-friendly, it's easy and quick to parse and manipulate with.

Comment: <div id="topic-title"></div>

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help:

```
$.post('topic.php', {id: id}, function(data){
    $("#message").html($(data).find("#your_dom_selector"));
    ...
}
```

Comment: This solution seem as bad design to me. You just gave this man a fish, when u were supposed to teach him how to fish. IMO.

Comment: Well i did not want to go very detail about this simple problem, so i think show a line of code is better than sentences about making solutions. 
Also, i would be gratefull if you could point out what do you mean by bad design?

Comment: i will be grateful if you teach me how to fish insted of him :D

Comment: ok what about if i want to retrieve this title and description in a lightbox how can i do it?

Comment: If you're using lightbox plugin for jquery, then i think this should do the trick:

$(data).find('title').lightbox( /* {your_options} */ );

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post('topic.php', {
    id: id
}, function(data) {
    $("#message")
        .html($(data).('attr', 'title'))
        .hide()
        .slideDown(500); //Fade in the data given by the topic.php file
});
return false;
});​
```